# How multiply python meteors objects

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Okay, so I'm trying to make a meteor game where you have to dodge the meteors. But I don't only want 1 meteor I want multiple. So how do I copy my first meteor into more?

Ive tried using a function to make more. But it gives me an error. Ive tried to use a while loop so it runs the meteor code 10 times but that didn't work

```
    import turtle
    import random
    # meteorgame by Daniel99oslo

    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.title("Meteor")
    wn.bgcolor("black")
    wn.setup(width=500, height=600)
    wn.tracer(0)

    #Player    
    Player = turtle.Turtle()
    Player.speed(0)
    Player.shape("square")
    Player.color("Blue")
    Player.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)
    Player.penup()
    Player.goto(0, -100)

    #Meteor    
    Meteor = turtle.Turtle()
    Meteor.speed(0)
    Meteor.shape("square")
    Meteor.color("red")
    Meteor.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)
    Meteor.penup()
    Meteor.goto(0, 290)

    y1 = (random.randint(500,600))
    y2 = Meteor.ycor()
    Meteor.sety(y1)


    # left/right
    def Player_Left():
        x = Player.xcor()
        x -= 5
        Player.setx(x)
    def Player_Right():
        x = Player.xcor()
        x += 5
        Player.setx(x)

    # Keyboard binds a/d
    wn.listen()
    wn.onkeypress(Player_Left, "a")
    wn.onkeypress(Player_Right, "d")

    # Main game loop
    while True:
        wn.update()

        #Meteor respawn/location
        x1 = (random.randint(-230,230))
        y = Meteor.ycor()
        y -= 0.1
        Meteor.sety(y)
        if Meteor.ycor() <-300:
            Meteor.sety(290)


            x = Meteor.xcor()
            Meteor.setx(x1)
        #Meteor hit player detection

        if Player.distance(Meteor) < 25:
            #Code that will kill player add here
            pass
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to python so expect inefficient code and stuff like that. But it still works.

Comment: You want to make a `list` of Meteors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just loop through the meteor code you have 10 times you still only get one result because the variable just gets overwritten each time you loop through it.  An easy way to handle this would be to create a list and store the meteors in there.

```
meteors = []
for i in range(10):
     Meteor = turtle.Turtle()
     ...
     meteors.append(Meteor)
```

Comment: Hey guys I managed to fix it. I had to use for and I had to list the objects. The game is now in alpha and I might add more to it. Atleast heres the alpha version I guees lol

Answer (score 0):

```
#code:
import turtle
import random
import time
# meteorgame by Daniel99oslo

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Meteor")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=500, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)




# Pen
score = 0
highscore = 0
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)









#Player

Player = turtle.Turtle()
Player.speed(0)
Player.shape("square")
Player.color("Blue")
Player.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)
Player.penup()
Player.goto(0, -100)



#Number of meteors
number_of_meteors = 10

#Meteor
meteors = []
for i in range(number_of_meteors):
    Meteor = turtle.Turtle()
    Meteor.speed(0)
    Meteor.shape("square")
    Meteor.color("red")
    Meteor.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)
    Meteor.penup()
    Meteor.setposition(0, 290)
    meteors.append(Meteor)

    def restart():
        for Meteor in meteors:
            y1 = (random.randint(500,2000))
            y2 = Meteor.ycor()
            Meteor.sety(y1)


# left/right
def Player_Left():
    x = Player.xcor()
    x -= 5
    Player.setx(x)
def Player_Right():
    x = Player.xcor()
    x += 5
    Player.setx(x)



# Keyboard binds a/d
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(Player_Left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(Player_Right, "d")



#Timer
Timer = turtle.Turtle()
Timer.speed(0)
Timer.shape("square")
Timer.color("orange")
Timer.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)
Timer.penup()
Timer.goto(-240, 290)



restart()


# Main game loop
while True:

        wn.update()


        #scoreadjust
        time = 0.2

        #Timerfaller
        y = Timer.ycor()
        y -= time
        Timer.sety(y)

        if Timer.ycor() <-300:
            Timer.goto(-240, 290)
            pen.clear()
            score += 10
            pen.write("Score: {}  Highscore: {}".format(score, highscore), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))


        #Meteor respawn/location


        for Meteor in meteors:
            x1 = (random.randint(-230,230))
            y = Meteor.ycor()
            y -= 0.1
            Meteor.sety(y)
            if Meteor.ycor() <-300:
                Meteor.sety(290)


                x = Meteor.xcor()
                Meteor.setx(x1)
        #Meteor hit player detection

        for Meteor in meteors:
            if Player.distance(Meteor) < 25:
                #Restart
                restart()

                #Score if tests
                if score == highscore:
                    score -= score
                if score > highscore:
                    highscore -= highscore
                if highscore > score:
                    score -= score
                highscore += score
                score -= score

                pen.clear()
                pen.write("Score: {}  Highscore: {}".format(score, highscore), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

                pass
```

Comment: Glad to hear things are working as intended.  I'm assuming the indentation on `def restart():` a typo?  There's no reason to define this function each time you create a meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to initialize one prototype meteor and then use its `.clone()` method to fill out your array of meteors:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

# ...

# Meteors
prototype_meteor = Turtle()
prototype_meteor.shape('square')
prototype_meteor.speed('fastest')
prototype_meteor.color('red')
prototype_meteor.penup()
prototype_meteor.setposition(randint(-230, 230), randint(250, 300))

meteors = [prototype_meteor]

for i in range(9):
    meteor = prototype_meteor.clone()
    meteor.setposition(randint(-230, 230), randint(250, 300))
    meteors.append(meteor)
```

Complete code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 600
FONT_SIZE = 24
FONT = ('Courier', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')
TURTLE_SIZE = 20

# left/right

def player_left():
    x = player.xcor() - 5

    player.setx(x)

def player_right():
    x = player.xcor() + 5

    player.setx(x)

def random_horizontal():
    return randint(TURTLE_SIZE - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - TURTLE_SIZE)

def random_vertical():
    return randint(HEIGHT / 3, HEIGHT/2 - TURTLE_SIZE)

def restart():
    for meteor in meteors:
        meteor.setposition(random_horizontal(), random_vertical())

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Meteor")
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
screen.tracer(0)

# Pen
score = 0
highscore = 0
pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.sety(260)
pen.write("Score: {}  Highscore: {}".format(score, highscore), align="center", font=FONT)

# Timer
timer = Turtle()
timer.shape('square')
timer.speed('fastest')
timer.color('orange')
timer.penup()
timer.goto(TURTLE_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2 - TURTLE_SIZE)

# Player
player = Turtle()
player.shape('square')
player.speed('fastest')
player.color('blue')

player.penup()
player.sety(-HEIGHT / 3)

# Meteors
number_of_meteors = 10

prototype_meteor = Turtle()
prototype_meteor.shape('square')
prototype_meteor.speed('fastest')
prototype_meteor.color('red')
prototype_meteor.penup()

meteors = [prototype_meteor] + [prototype_meteor.clone() for i in range(number_of_meteors - 1)]

restart()

# Keyboard binds a/d
screen.onkeypress(player_left, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(player_right, 'd')
screen.listen()

# Main game loop
while True:

    timer.sety(timer.ycor() - 0.2)

    if timer.ycor() < TURTLE_SIZE - HEIGHT/2:
        timer.goto(TURTLE_SIZE/2 - WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2 - TURTLE_SIZE)
        score += 10

    for meteor in meteors:
        # Meteor respawn/location

        y = meteor.ycor() - 1

        if y < TURTLE_SIZE - HEIGHT/2:
            meteor.setposition(random_horizontal(), random_vertical())
        else:
            meteor.sety(y)

        # Meteor hit player detection

        if player.distance(meteor) < TURTLE_SIZE:
            score -= 20
            restart()
            break

    if score > highscore:
        highscore = score

    pen.clear()
    pen.write("Score: {}  Highscore: {}".format(score, highscore), align="center", font=FONT)

    screen.update()
```